# Can't access locally hosted web server on same network

Tags: networking, apache-http-server, port-forwarding, raspberry-pi, webserver

I have set up a Raspberry Pi as a web server on my local network.

Everything has mostly been fine for 2 years until today when I went to check the website and found I am unable to visit the site it from within my local network (URL or IP address).

I can access it fine from an external network.

I can also SSH onto the machine using its IP address.

However, when I try to navigate to the URL or local/external IP address using Google Chrome/Safari/etc, it loads forever and fails.

I haven't changed a single thing in my network, nor with the Raspberry Pi.

What could this possibly be?

Comment: Did you tried to restart raspberry pi? Did you updated recently apache?

Comment: I restarted the Raspberry Pi and Apache. I haven't updated Apache, should I try that?

Comment: What is in apache log? Do you see your attempts to connect? Do you use some iptables solutions (fail2ban for example)? Try also to restart your router